# How to concat integer and string inside recursive function in C

Tags: c, string, recursion, integer, concatenation

guys, I want to make a program to generate all combination elements. for example if user input (n) = 3, so the output must be like this :

```
1
12
123
13
2
23
3
```

I have a problem to concat integer and string inside recursive function..

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rekursif(int m, int n, char angka[100]){
    int i;
    for(i=m; i<=n; i++){
        sprintf(angka, "%s %d", angka, i);
        printf("%s \n", angka);
        rekursif(i+1,n,angka);
    }
}

int main(){
    rekursif(1,5,"");
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the program, command prompt is not responding. I guess, the problem is in concation ( sprintf(angka, "%s %d", angka, i); ) 
please help me to solve this problem. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `""` as the function argument, you are trying to modify a string literal, which is undefined behavior. Instead, do:

```
int main(){
    char str[100];
    rekursif(1, 5, str);
    return 0;
}
```

Be careful with buffer overflow in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Command prompt is running well. But if I input n = 3 the result is like this 

1
12
123
1233
12332
123323
1233233

I realize that I was wrong, the variable angka must be reset in specific condition. is there another way to solve this problem beside sprintf function? thanks

Comment: @stranger Since you can debug the program now, it's best that you try it first before asking for help.

Comment: Sorry, I just try debug the program right now, and it solved. Thanks. I just need to back up the variable angka into another variable before concation.